# Change <h2> dynamically on ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im a total newbie when it comes to ionic and i have been trying to change an H1 tag dynamically inside a ion-header-bar without any success. This is the part of HTML that i need to work with:

```
<ion-header-bar class="cabecera bar-light">
   <div class="buttons buttons-left header-item"><span class="left-buttons">
      <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon texto-azul" menu-toggle="left">
      </button>
        </span></div>
        <img src="img/img-logo.jpg" alt="logo-banco" class="cabecera__logo"/>
        <h1 class="title">{Dynamic h1 here}</h1>
      <i class="ion-help-circled"></i>
</ion-header-bar>
```

This my app.js

```
.controller('AppController', function($scope) {

console.log("Not initialize");
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());

function initialize() {
  console.log("Initialize");
  var mapOptions = {
    // the Teide ;-)
    center: {lat: 41.391134, lng: 2.155260},
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: []
    },
    panControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    }
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), mapOptions);
  $scope.map = map;
}
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

 $stateProvider

.state('login', {
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
  name: 'login',
  controller:'MainCtrl'  
})

.state('menu', {
  templateUrl: 'menu.html',
  name:'menu',
  controller:'MainCtrl'
})

.state('detalle-partes', {
  templateUrl: 'detalle-partes.html',
  name:'detalle-partes',
  controller:'MainCtrl'
})

})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    "use strict";

/* Items for left side menu. */
$scope.menuItems = [
    {id: 'login', name: 'Login'},
    {id: 'menu', name: 'Menu'},
    {id: 'detalle-partes', name: 'Partes: Detalle'},
    {id: 'seguimiento-partes', name: 'Partes: Seguimient'},
    {id: 'grua', name: 'Grua'},
    {id: 'registre', name: 'Registre'},
    {id: 'renting-robo', name: 'Renting: Robo'},
    {id: 'taller', name: 'Taller'},
    {id: 'taller-mecanica', name: 'Taller: Mecánica'}
];

$scope.enterState = function(stateID) {
      console.log(stateID);
        $state.transitionTo(stateID);
};

$scope.$state = $state;
})
```

What i need to do is to change that H1 with the template title, any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: And where do you have your template title?

Answer (score 0):

Add the title to the scope from your controller.

Then just pass it to the view like you would in angular.

**In Controller**

```
$scope.title = 'MyTitle';
```

**In View**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h>
```

Be sure to add the right controller to your state, or your view.
You are adding MainCtrl to both of your states. So if you added the

```
 $scope.title = "MyTitle";
```

to the AppController, as you named it, you need to add that controller to the view you want the data to go to.

Comment: How would you pass the title in angular ? as i said before im a total newbie when it comes to ionic and angular, thanks ! @BastianBuhrkall